# collectstatic collects additional files to STATICFILES_DIRS in django

Tags: python, django, static, collectstatic

My settings looks like this:

```
STATIC_URL  = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "polls/static/"),
)
```

So now when I run `collectstatic` it also collects stuff from

> '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css

I understand that `collectstatic` goes through the `INSTALLED_APPS` according to [here](http://django-staticfiles.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/commands.html)

whic is fine but `/usr/local` is not in the `INSTALLED_APPS`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's collecting static files for the Django Admin app. Your Django in installed in `/usr/local ...`.

Comment: ah ok, so how am I going to prevent `collectstatic` from copying these other files? with `--exclude` ?

Comment: It's collected because you have `'django.contrib.admin',` in your installed apps. If you don't need admin, you can delete it from installed apps, otherwise it will need the static files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have `django.contrib.admin` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, that why when you run `collectstatic`,  it collect its static files.